# Can I tell ng-table to redistribute the items in the table according to items per page?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filtering, ngtable

*I´m an angular newbie* using the [ng-table](http://ng-table.com/) directive.

**TL;DR;**
Is there any way I can tell ng-table to redistribute the items in the table according to items per page after table has finished loading?

**The long story**
I have a collection of items including subitems that I bind to the ng-table and that works just fine with pagination and items per page selection. My problem is that when I try to apply a filter, the table leaves the items on their original pages. Let´s say that I have 5000 items in the table, spread over 500 pages each containing 10 items. The filtering I have implemented works just fine but it leaves the items on the original pages, for instance, if an item with STId=1826 is initially put on page 4512 and I filter for 1826, it will remain on that page, even if there are no more items in the entire collection. Of course, this is because the ng-table is already loaded and needs to reload for this to work. But I figure, since the collection is already in memory on the client, there must be some way to redistribute the items.

I know there is a native ng-table filter function but suffice it to say that I see no way it is possible for me to use.

I have a collection of items:

```
SigningTasks: [
    {
      "CS": "Init",
      "STId": 6637,
      "CivicNumber": "198301101997",
      "Culture": {
        "CultureId": 1,
        "CountryCode": "SE",
        "LanguageCode": "sv",
        "Name": "Sverige, svenska"
      },
      "Status": "InitDone",
      "DateCreated": "2015-06-26T13:45:13.723",
      "GroupName": "Group1",
    },
    ...
]
```

and table parameters:

```
vm.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
    page: 1,
    count: 10,
    sorting: {
        DateCreated: 'desc'
    }
},
{
    total: vm.List.length,
    counts: [10, 25, 50, 100, 250, 500, 1000],
    getData: function ($defer, params) {
        var filteredData = $filter('filter')(vm.List, params.filter());
        params.total(filteredData.length);

        var orderedData = params.sorting() ? $filter('orderBy')(filteredData, params.orderBy()) : filteredData;
        $defer.resolve(orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
    }
});
```

and a table:

```
<table ng-table="vm.tableParams">
    <tr ng-repeat="task in $data | filter:vm.filterTasks(vm.CivicNumber)">
    ...
    </tr>
</table>
```

and a filter function:

```
vm.filterTasks = function (civicNumber) {
    return function (task) {
        var includeItem = true;

        if (civicNumber !== null && civicNumber !== undefined && civicNumber !== "") {
            includeItem = task.CivicNumber.includes(civicNumber);
        }
        return includeItem;
        }
    };
```